# How to avoid short circuit on battery wires on a charging circuit

Tags: diodes, battery-charging, short-circuit, mobile-robot

I built a mobile robot which uses 24Vdc 200Ah battery pack to power 2 DC motors.
The circuit used to power the system is pretty robust, I used a relay to switch the motor controllers on and off, and there are fuses for each circuit branch.

The problem is related to the charging circuit: I placed a panel connector on the robot frame and this connector is directly connected to the battery terminals. I connect the battery charger to this connector when I need to charge them.
Everything works fine, but the wires are always connected to the battery even when the robot is powered off. Is there any way to avoid short circuits on these wires? If something comes in contact with the connector, a short circuit could happen.
I placed a fuse on the positive wire between the battery and the connector, but I would like to find a correct solution to avoid sparks or shorts.

What are the solutions uses in this case?

Thank you

Comment: The general solution is to choose a connector which has contacts which cannot be casually shorted together.

Comment: I already have it, the connector is sealed and protected, but if someone try to unmount it, for example, for maintenance, the two wires could touch each other and generate sparks.

Comment: Create a removable structure that has the connectors and wires sealed within a physically solid insulator block. Use spring loaded pressure contacts to the battery. Pull the structure and shelve it when not in use?

Comment: "if someone try to unmount it, for example, for maintenance" - then the maintenance procedure should be to disconnect the battery wiring 1st...

Comment: "_if someone try to unmount it, for example, for maintenance, the two wires could touch each other and generate sparks_" - are you saying there are exposed conductors internally? If so, could you use an insulator (like heatshrink) to cover these up? A photo of the problem area would likely help here.

Comment: No, I mean that if someone disconnect the wires from the connector, then these wires can touch each other and generate sparks. Or even if vibrations or any other event make the wire disconnect from the connector, a short circuit can occur. The wires are connected to the connector through fast-on connectors.

Comment: You should use insulated Fast-On connectors.

Comment: install a fuse in the charging circuit, next to the battery terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a 3 poles connector. In the robot frame, connect one pole to negative of battery, one for the coil of a relay (pin 3), and positive of battery through a contact of this relay (and your fuse). The other terminal of the coil of relay should be connected to positive of battery. In the plug for the charger, make a jumper from pin 3 to negative, so when your connect this plug, will activate the relay. Withour inserting the plug you only get negative from battery and the coil of the realy, no positive is available.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz7zJI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For some 3 phase motor plugs, I also used 5 poles connector, 3 phases+ground, and one of the male contacts was used to close a limit switch in the box to enable starter. That way the operator can plug without power in the socket.

Comment: This is a wonderful and smart solution! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a (Shottky) diode in series close to the battery. In that way the part of the wire further from the battery is safeguarded against shorting the battery.

If one side of the battery is grounded, the diode is of course best placed in the wire going to the other side.

Comment: The problem is that the diode will gave a voltage drop across the battery and the battery charger could not properly charge the battery.

Comment: Battery packs that are rated "24V" will usually have a voltage range like for instance 22.4V – 28.8V. The 0.5 V drop from a (big) Shottkey diode will not be too much of a problem. But indeed it would charge the pack a little bit less than without the diode.